# Multiple dynamic entry scripts in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let's say I have an app structure like this

```
app/
   modules/
      module1/
         <other files>
         script.js
      module2/
         <other files>
         script.js
      module3/
         <other files>
         script.js
   lib/
      <some common/shared scripts to import from>
public/
   js/
```

How can I configure webpack to bundle and output each `script.js` (which will be importing various libs/utilities from the common lib folder) into a structure like this?

e.g.

```
public/js/module1/script.js
public/js/module2/script.js
```

But without individually defining each entry file? Something like gulp does with `/**/*.js` syntax?

My goal is NOT to have to maintain my `webpack.config.js` file each time I add a new module/component.

Comment: A webpack config file is JavaScript. You can read the directory structure and build the desired paths.

Comment: Did you ever find out how?

Answer (score 4):

You need glob package and set `entry` and `output` in your `webpack.config.js`.
Example when `webpack.config.js` in root dir.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var glob = require('glob');

//Generate object for webpack entry
//rename './app/modules/module1/script.js' -> 'module1/script'
var entryObject = glob.sync('./app/modules/**/script.js').reduce(
    function (entries, entry) {
        var matchForRename = /^\.\/app\/modules\/([\w\d_]+\/script)\.js$/g.exec(entry);

        if (matchForRename !== null && typeof matchForRename[1] !== 'undefined') {
            entries[matchForRename[1]] = entry;
        }

        return entries;
    }, 
    {}
);

module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: entryObject,//{'moduleName/script': './app/modules/moduleName/script.js', ...}
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: '[name].js'//'moduleName/script.js', [name] - key from entryObject
    }
    ...
};
```

If you will have error with fs like " can't resolve 'fs' " add option

```
node: {
    fs: "empty"
}
```

Also, you can bundle your files from `<other files>` into public script.js using other entryObject.

```
var entryObject = glob.sync('./app/modules/**/*.js').reduce(
    function (entries, entry) {
        var matchForRename = /^\.\/app\/modules\/([\w\d_]+)\/.+\.js$/g.exec(entry);

        if (matchForRename !== null && typeof matchForRename[1] !== 'undefined') {
            var entryName = matchForRename[1] + '/script';

            if (typeof entries[entryName] !== 'undefined') {
                entries[entryName].push(entry);
            } else {
                entries[entryName] = [entry];
            }

        }

        return entries;
    },
    {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet and adjust it for your needs

```
const path = require('path')
const glob = require('glob')

const entries = glob.sync('./src/entry/*').reduce((entries, entry) => {
    const entryName = path.parse(entry).name
    entries[entryName] = entry

    return entries
}, {});

module.exports = {
    entry: entries,
...
```

`'./src/entry/*'` - regex to find files from which your entries will be constructed

`const entryName = path.parse(entry).name` - extract filename from file path

`entries[entryName] = entry` - construct entry record

as a result you will have something like

```
{
    file1: 'path/to/file1.js',
    file2: 'path/to/file2.js',
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hello zvar, welcome to StackOverflow. Please give explanations to that code snippet, why does it works and how does it works? Just giving a sample code like that wouldn't really help anyone. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NicholasD updated. thanks for pointing. hope it will now have more sense and be more helpful